# What is wrong with this merge sort?

Tags: java, sorting, groovy, mergesort

```
int[] input = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
mergeSort(input,0,input.length)

void mergeSort(int[] A,int p,int r){
    if(p < r){
        int q = (int) Math.floor((p+r)/2)
        mergeSort(A,p,q)
        mergeSort(A,q+1,r)
        merge(A,p,q,r)
    }
}

void merge(int[] A,int p,int q,int r){
    int i = 0
    int j = 0
    int n1 = q - p + 1
    int n2 = r - q
    int[] L = new int[n1]
    int[] R = new int[n2]
    for(;i<n1;i++){ L[i] = A[p+i-1] }
    for(;j<n2;j++){ R[j] = A[q+j] }
    i = j = 0
    for(int k = p; k < r; k++){
        if(L[i] <= R[j]){ A[k] = L[i++] }
        else{ A[k] = R[j++] }
    }
}
```

This is a direct implementation of merge sort from the `Introduction to Algorithms` book. Although it looks correct, it ends with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.

I have been trying to debug it but couldn't. I'd like to know what's going wrong and how to correct it.

Runnable Example: http://ideone.com/GhuuSd

Comment: Everywhere you mess with indexes and trying to access array's elements without checking for bounds, you're messing with the devil.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Would you please correct the code? :)

Comment: Can't you see which line the exception was thrown from?

Comment: @Useless It points to the comparison line `if(L[i] <= R[j])`

Comment: is it so that you should implement using this code snippet only? or any new way can be used ?

Comment: @BhargavModi correcting this code snippet would be better :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, although this is Groovy and therefore the negative index highlighted by @Useless won't throw an exception, it is indicative of a problem.

I think you have two problems: *Caveat: I'm not familiar with the exact presentation in "Introduction to Algorithms"*

1. Your indices into A to populate L and R are off by one - they should be [p+i] (thus avoiding the possible negative index issue) and [q+j+1]. **Note with this amendment you need to pass in length-1 as the starting argument for r**
2. in your test at the bottom to determine which of L and R to use in re-populating elements of A, you do not check for i or j running beyond the length of those arrays (i.e. is i >= n1 or j >= n2).  In these cases (i.e. one of L or R has "run out" of members), you should use the other array.

Code below works for your example, I haven't tested it extensively but have tried cases with repeated numbers, negative etc and believe it should hold up:

```
int[] input = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
mergeSort(input,0,input.length-1)
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input))     

void mergeSort(int[] A,int p,int r){
    if(p < r){
        int q = (int) Math.floor((p+r)/2)
        mergeSort(A,p,q)
        mergeSort(A,q+1,r)
        merge(A,p,q,r)
    }
}

void merge(int[] A,int p,int q,int r) {
    int i = 0
    int j = 0
    int n1 = q - p + 1
    int n2 = r - q
    int[] L = new int[n1]
    int[] R = new int[n2]
    for(;i<n1;i++){ L[i] = A[p+i] }
    for(;j<n2;j++){ R[j] = A[q+j+1] }
    i = j = 0
    for(int k = p; k <= r; k++){
        if(j >= n2 || (i < n1 && L[i] < R[j] )) { A[k] = L[i++] }
        else{ A[k] = R[j++] }
    }    
}
```

Comment: The book uses `1` indexing for arrays instead of `0`. Is that what is causing the problem?

Comment: Ah. Yes, probably - that would do it.  If you look at the edits I've made it's effectively "shifting" everything one place.  The checks for "running out" of members in L and R at the end would probably still be required either way.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0
...
for(;i<n1;i++){ L[i] = A[p+i-1] }
```

What is the index into A on your first iteration, where p is zero?

Comment: This isnt the source of the problems. I ran the example on IdeOne and posted the link, just in case anyone would like to see :)

Comment: @LittleChild - what you have posted on IdeOne is not correct. please see this correct version of your code. http://ideone.com/GbPicR. And it fails at point Useless has mentioned because its going to evaluate to -1.